# navigationController!.pushViewController giving Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value:

Tags: swift, navigationcontroller

I am trying to navigate from one Storyboard to another Storyboard. Here is my code -

```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                     let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detail") as! detailsArticle
                     controller.jsonData = json2["post"]
                    
                    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

However, when I try to navigate after clicking the button which runs the above code, I get exception error:

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

How do I solve this?

Comment: On which line are you getting this error?

Comment: self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 places you could be getting the crash.

1. The identifier of the `detailsArticle` is not set as "detail".
2. The controller you're trying to push onto is not embedded in `navigationController`.

Try running and check the console to see the debug messages I've added:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
guard let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detail") as? detailsArticle else { print("detail vc id not set"); return }
controller.jsonData = json2["post"]
guard let navigationController = navigationController else { print("this vc is not embedded in navigationController"); return }
navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

From the comments it's the 2nd one causing the issue. To fix it here are the steps:

1. Go to `<StoryboardName>.storyboard` where the current `UIViewController` sub-class is located and select the current `UIViewController` scene.
2. From the `Menu bar` choose `Editor` and `Embedd In` and select `Navigation Controller`.

Comment: Its giving this vc is not embedded in navigationController.. How do I embed it in navigationcontroller?

Comment: The code which I have shown is for another storyboard Xyz and not main.storyboard. Do I have to embed navigation controller in Xyz or main?

Comment: However, detailsArticle is in main.storyboard

Comment: You should probably go to xyz where the current view controller is located.

Comment: please check ur mail

Comment: are you still not able to fix it? I don't think it's so hard to embed a VC in nav VC.